# How do I get python code to execute properly from a button click when an alert is included as action from the button click?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have been having trouble getting alerts to work with an html button press that also calls a url. Describing the problem in more detail, I have a button that when pressed calls a url which from my urls.py file and views.py file calls some python code that plays a video but when I include an alert to trigger when the button is pressed, the python code does not get executed but the alert shows up without any problem. My question is how do I make these two actions compatible on a single button click so that both are executed properly? Also using the Django framework if that provides more information.

This is the html and javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_alert() {
alert("The View Is Now Playing in a New Window");
} 
</script>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/VideoPlayer" role="button"  onclick="show_alert()">Play Video</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to execute server side and client side code you need to use XHR or simply [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

`<a href=''></a>` will redirect page to `href`'s url, for this you need to add 'return false' to your JavaScript click method

like this

```
`function click(){
   alert();
   // call your ajax here
   return false;
}`
```

hopefully this can help you